# How to find center of mass of arc $r=2\sin{\theta}+4\cos{\theta}$?

Tags: calculus

From textbook I had read, i have known that center of mass of an flat arc is $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ with
$$
\bar{x}=\frac{\int x\ ds}{\int ds}\text{  ;   }\bar{y}=\frac{\int y\ ds}{\int ds}
$$
with $ds$ is arc's differential.

Now i get confused with the formula for finding center of mass of arc in polar coordinates...
Thanks :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366994/center-of-mass-of-a-circle

Comment: this problem is different. I mean for the arbitrary flat arc curve, not "just" a circle.

Comment: You can write $ds$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The curve has parametric equations $$x=r \cos \theta\quad ,\quad y=r \sin \theta$$ so (verify) $$\left(\frac {ds}{d\theta}\right)^2=\left(\frac {dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac {dy}{d\theta}\right)^2=r^2+\left(\frac {dr}{d\theta}\right)^2$$